# Голубые каски - в кавычках или без?

Tags: пунктуация, названия

Кавычится ли сочетание **"голубые каски"**?

Answer (score 2):

Да, **кавычки ставятся**, сочетание имеет условное значение.

Розенталь: 8) слова, употребленные в условном значении (применительно к ситуации или контексту): На манёврах «красные» выступали против «зелёных». [Газ.]; [РАЗДЕЛ 17. УПОТРЕБЛЕНИЕ КАВЫЧЕК](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=169)

**Пример:** Понятие «голубые каски», или «голубые береты» ООН, прочно вошли в политический обиход последних десятилетий.

**Почему они так называются:**

[Почему миротворцы ООН носят голубые каски? | aif.ru](http://www.aif.ru/dontknows/file/pochemu_mirotvorcy_oon_nosyat_golubye_kaski)